# Configuring multiple queues with a topic exchange and using routing key to direct the message specific queue with spring cloud streams

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Configuring multiple queues with a topic exchange and using routing key to direct the message specific queue with spring cloud streams

My requirement is example I have the queues and exchange defined as below in consumer end

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputA.destination=Common-Exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputA.group=A-Queue

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputB.destination=Common-Exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputB.group=B-Queue
```

- I should be able to specify the routing key in the consumer just like
  we do it in AMQP where we can pass the exchange queue and routing key
  to create the binding
- I should be able to set the routing key when sending the message in
  producer end using MessageBuilder

  channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build())

Of course we can use one queue and use headers to direct different type of messages but I need to know how multiple queue connected to a single exchange work with streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Rabbit binder documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_configuration_options).

- On the consumer side, set the `bindingRoutingKey` consumer binding property.
- On the producer side, the the `routingKeyExpression` producer binding property (e.g. `headers['routingKey']` and set that header as needed).

Also see [Using Existing Queues/Exchanges](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges).

Comment: If we have One exchange A, 2 queues A.a and A.b, and i want to have only one Consumer method to consume data from two topics because they send the same forme of data. How can i do that with the new version Spring Cloud Stream based on Consumer?

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments on old answers. That topology is not currently supported by Spring Cloud Stream using only properties; you can consume from 2 queues with the same name bound to 2 different exchanges, but not 2 queues with different names bound to the same exchange. You can, however, do it using a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to add the second queue to the container. If you need an example of how to do that, ask a new question so I can answer it.